# Custom MediaTypeFormatter, why IKeyValueModel and not my model type?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, mediatypeformatter

I am trying to do a custom implementation of a `MediaTypeFormatter`, but the method `bool CanReadType(Type type)` is always called with the type `IKeyValueModel`, instead my type `MyProduct`.

In my API controller I have:

```
[HttpPost]
public Task Save(MyProduct product)
```

I have seen some examples ( [example 1](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-JSONNET-with-ASPNET-b2423706/view/Discussions#content), [example 2](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Mar/09/Using-an-alternate-JSON-Serializer-in-ASPNET-Web-API)), and I have also tried the code:

```
protected override bool CanReadType(Type type)
{
    if (type == typeof(IKeyValueModel))
        return false;
      return true;
}
```

But then I get a "MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object", because my model type has no parameterless constructor. So it looks like because `CanReadType` returns false to `IKeyValueModel`, the framework uses another media type formatter. Actually, the method `OnReadFromStreamAsync` is never hit.

I want to be able of controlling how my models are deserialized, I want to get the real type and not `IKeyValueModel`.

This was already working great in MVC with model binders.

Cheers.

**UPDATE 2012/05/29:**

If I remove the default json formatter it works:

```
    public static void RegisterApis(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Formatters.Clear();
```

But then I will like to keep both, how could I indicate which one I want to use?

Regards.

Comment: Why do you need a custom `MediaTypeFormatter`?

Comment: Try latest code(nightly build), there is no IKeyValueModel in current source. It has been removed/deleted by team.  http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/BradWilson/AspNetWebStack/changeset/changes/5648aed69341

Comment: @Aliostad I need a custom MediaTypeFormatter to control how my objects are serialized and deserialized to JSON.

Comment: @user960567 so we can expect big changes in the release?

Comment: @NullOrEmpty, henrik is continuously helping us, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/

Comment: I tried with the latest version, but the dependency resolver does not work with ninject, i think i will have to wait :'(

Answer (score 3):

If you need to control serialisation, it is better to use Json.NET's flexibility features (see [here](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/), [here](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/SerializationAttributes.html) and [here](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/SerializationSettings.html)) to control rather than write a media type formatter just for that.

Json.NET [now](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/05/03/asp-net-web-api-updates-may-3.aspx) is the default formatter in the ASP.NET Web API.

---

## UPDATE

> My objects don't have parameterless constructors and the properties
>   are readonly. I have also objects that inherit from DynamicObject, so
>   let's say that my business entities are not trivial.

I probably can show you how to shoot yourself in the foot. But I would rather explain how to avoid having these problems as I believe you are having them since there are anti-patterns in you approach.

First of all, what you are looking for is not another media type formatter. You need a different serializer or just need to configure your serializer.

But more importantly, serializing your business entities straight to the client is not such a great idea. We need DTOs which here are called view models. Such classes are only state holders, no logic, no magic. Serializing them should be no issue.

You can use AutoMapper, etc to map your entities to view models with no more development cost. **It is always advised to abstract away your domain models from the presentation layer.**

Comment: My objects don't have parameterless constructors and the properties are readonly. I have also objects that inherit from DynamicObject, so let's say that my business entities are not trivial. I am actually using JSON.NET under the hood, but I need to use it in a custom way.

Comment: thanks for your input, but the question is about something else. We are ACTUALLY creating DTOs when we create JSON entities, that  is the point of JSON :) So, I need a way to control how those JSON DTOs transforms in/from my business entities... As I stated already, my business objects are dynamics (System.Dynamic), this is not about serialize an object with all its properties, this is about create a JSON transport object from my dynamic business object and viceversa.